# Subclassed QStyledItemDelegate ignores Stylesheet

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` to remove the focus rectangle in a `QComboBox`.

Even though I'm calling the base implementation of the paint function and nothing else, the result is very different. It looks as if only the parts of the style-sheet that influence the bounding box of the item are taken into consideration.

```
class PStyledItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(PStyledItemDelegate, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

    def paint(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(*args, **kwargs)
```

What do I have to do to get it to paint exactly as a unmodified `QStyledItemDelegate`?

Comment: Where is your stylesheet defined and what does it look like? Also, can you attach screeenshots?

Comment: This may be caused by a PySide bug. What version are you using, and have you tested your code with PyQt4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested I tried replacing PySide with PyQt4 and now it works, so it appears to be a bug. I also update PySide from 1.1.2 to 1.2.1 but the result is the same.

Unfortunately the switch breaks other parts of my code, but if there are no other suggestions I'm going to accept this as answer.

**EDIT**
The Bug is tracked [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/PYSIDE-152)